# javaScript globe with clickable pins

Tags: javascript

I need to have clickable event within my pop ups, but I can't seem identify the element. When the function get invoked, the element comes back as 'null'.

I tried to have all the addEventlistener in a setTimeout function.

```
var marker = WE.marker([35.6804, 139.769]).addTo(earth);
marker
    .bindPopup(
        "<b>Tokyo</b><br /><span style='font-size:10px;'>Innovation Place Douglas Road Godalming Surrey GU7 1JX<button id='btn-overlay'>Click me</button></span>",
        {
            maxWidth: 150,
            closeButton: true,
        }
    )
    .closePopup();

    // eventhandler function...
    var element = document.querySelector('btn-overlay');
    console.log("element", element);
    element.addEventListener(
        "click",
        function () {
            /* do stuff here*/
        },
        false
    );
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: well are you binding the event after the element is added to the page?

Comment: Yes, I believe so, I've re-arrange where my eventListener is and it works now...
Please have a look, see what you think https://codepen.io/Joejoe123/pen/OKrWLe